# How do you turn off method autocompletion on open parenthesis in NetBeans 7.0?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I guess I'm a quick typer because if I type the characters

```
ArrayList myArray;
myArray.size(
```

NetBeans auto complete puts the following in my editor

```
ArrayList myArray;
myArray.add(someVar);
```

Why?  Because the auto completion doesn't have time to find and filter all the method names by the time I type '('.  So it takes the the first one from the list it has created and filtered so far: "add".  Grrrr!!!

I want to keep method name completion, but I don't want it to happen on '('.  I haven't been able to find out how to fine tune this awesome feature to stop it from mangling my code.

Comment: I've tried to type really fast those characters in netbeans and I never get "add" instead of "size" if I manually type "size". It's really weird that problem you're having.

Comment: Isn't it!  It's super annoying!! I run into it all the time when I'm coding... I've actually learned to pause before typing '(' and wait for the autocompletion to catch up... super annoying!!  Perhaps your computer is much faster than mine and gets the autocompletion before you finish typing.  I type 100+ words a minute on a good day, that means those 5 characters go by in less than half a second.  Lots of times I don't even see the autocompletion suggestions before I've finished and the code has been automangled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce you problem in NetBeans 7.1.2. Maybe I'm not typing fast enough...

Take a look at the Options to switch off some of the code completion options: Tools->Options, select the Editor section, then the Code Completion tab.
[image]

Comment: I haven't yet tried this, but it looks like the answer I need, thanks!

Comment: I don't know why code completion is so slow in Netbeans, probably because I have various plugins installed that slow it down... I have the jvim plugin installed, maybe that's it. I used your suggestion and now I use Ctrl-Space to bring up the list of auto-completions when I want to use them. Now my code is what I type, always!

Answer (score 0):

A.S. This is a comment but I don't have the rep.

I definitely experience this issue, and similar ones in other IDEs like Eclipse or Qt Creator - though I can't always be bothered figuring out how they happened. For example in Qt Creator I type:

```
size_t len = array.size();
```

and it becomes

```
size_t len = array.size(;)
```

because it didn't recognize quickly enough that I wanted to type over the closing ')'.

It is even more annoying when the editor doesn't allow overwriting or tab-jumping those braces as you have to press Right arrow.