# Disable place holders for autocompletion in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea

Whenever it autocompletes an function name, netbeans fills out some place holders within the parentheses, and as I use the jVi plugin, it takes two escapes to exit from there, or even more when you have nested functions, which is very annoying.

[image]

IntelliJ takes a more sensible approach, it gives you an empty pair of parentheses and pops up a hint:

[image]

I could have switched to IntelliJ, but I also miss the Shift+F11 shortcut for quickly building a jar file in netbeans. If only I can have the best from both worlds!

Comment: Use eclipse? Best of all worlds .... just kidding... but had to be said.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829727/how-do-you-turn-off-method-autocompletion-on-open-parenthesis-in-netbeans-7-0 help?

Comment: that question seems different, and the solution there does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Guess Filled Method Arguments" may help.
[image]

Comment: I have already tried that, it doesn't work, at least not in netbeans 7.4 on Ubuntu Linux.