# Netbeans auto-completion Java

Tags: java, netbeans

is there a way to disable the auto-completion for String in netbeans for java? 
Example I type `"` netbeans writes `""`. I hope you know what i mean.

Comment: Yes I do and it's very annoying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you turn off method autocompletion on open parenthesis in NetBeans 7.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829727/how-do-you-turn-off-method-autocompletion-on-open-parenthesis-in-netbeans-7-0)

Answer (score 2):

Goto Tools->Options->Editor->Code Completion and uncheck `Insert Closing Brackets Automatically`

Comment: Presumably that sorts out the automatic insertion of `""` too?

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't get exactly get what you are saying.. When you uncheck that option, when you enter `"` another `"` will not be added